# Django and frontend. How not to use Django urls and templates

Tags: django, frontend

Ordinary concept is to use `urls.py` and `views.py`. So you define in `urls.py` for main page smth like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', project.views.index),
]
```

and this in `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

But I saw code where there wasn't any url in `urls.py` for the main page and any others pages.

I can realise, that further routing can be done with this modern frameworks and their routing modules. **But I can't realise where is the entrypoint, which says: "Take this main Html page for this route".**

It's a very interesting approach, so I want to implement it too, but I don't even know how to find the suitable words to find any material in order to realise this.

Comment: May you provide the code you saw? AFAIK there is no way to bind html templates directly to urls without using a view in between.

Comment: unfortunately no, internal project

Comment: Did you see a flask project, maybe? Or something that used [Werkzeug routing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/viewdecorators/)?

Comment: @Withnail no, that was Django project. Single page app, as zubhav mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about a single-page app? Possibly using Django REST framework with a front-end framework like Angular and React. You would only declare one URL for the single page and then let front-end handle the routing.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, single-page app, that's what I am looking for. Should I declare this entry page with Django `views.py` and `urls.py`? Or there is another way to do this?

Comment: Yes, I would declare the entry page like that! Just create a index.html and link it to a view!